# Mvc 5 Web Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, web-config

OK....I have been trying to get this page published for a while...

My latest issue is:

Error       Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic

Here is the web.config:

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
      type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, 
      Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
      type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, 
      Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   </system.webServer>
```

The

is where it is erroring...These lines are added on publishing automatically, then error.  Any Ideas?

My final goal is to publish server errors to the browser so I can troubleshoot.

Comment: Missed a bit the   <compilation />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />  is where the error occurs

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant information (not in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <clear />
            <remove statusCode="403" />
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <remove statusCode="500" />
            <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Unauthorized" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

This is an example how you config httpErrors.

For more details information, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/)